# Oracle SQLLDR - Using parameter file to specify multiple log, dsc, bad files

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I'm not sure how to handle this situation loading files into a single table with Oracle SQLLDR.
I have multiple infiles, which I'm able to load with no problems. However, I want to specify individual log files, bad files, and discard directories/files for each of them in my parameter file. Is this possible? I've tried listing them in the parameter file, with spaces between the file names, but that doesn't seem to work. I have not found instructions or examples of how to do this anywhere.

I use a command to include the parameter file:

```
sqlldr user/password@pdbxxxxx PARFILE=/directory/parameter_file.par
```

My parameter file example:

```
    CONTROL=/directory/control_file.ctl
    LOG=/directory/log_file.log
    BAD=/directory/bad_file.bad
    DISCARD=/directory/discard_file.dsc
    DISCARDMAX=100000000
    DATA=/directory/data_file-01.csv
    DIRECT=FALSE
```

My control file example:

```
load data
infile '/directory/data_file-01.csv'
infile '/directory/data_file-02.csv'
infile '/directory/data_file-03.csv'
APPEND INTO TABLE my_table
                fields terminated by "," optionally enclosed by '"'
                TRAILING NULLCOLS
  (
        col1 CHAR
    ,   col2 CHAR                  
    ,   col3 CHAR
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [Specifying multiple data files](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-C3A0A205-6265-4130-ABAB-DD277188E850.htm#SUTIL1065), as described in documentation.

Excerpt:

> To load data from multiple data files in one SQL*Loader run, use an INFILE clause for each data file.

> You can also specify a separate discard file and bad file for each data file. In such a case, the separate bad files and discard files must be declared immediately after each data file name.

A few examples:

```
INFILE  mydat1.dat  BADFILE  mydat1.bad  DISCARDFILE mydat1.dis 
INFILE  mydat2.dat 
INFILE  mydat3.dat  DISCARDFILE  mydat3.dis
```

Comment: Thanks. This would require editing the control file, right? I was looking for a solution where I could add these specifications to the parameter file.

Comment: I don't think you can, unless you create a control file *dynamically*. That would require a script on the operating system level, using programming language of your choice.